# serial communication protocols in embedded system

Tags: protocols

There are some common protocols used in embedded systems such as I2C,CAN, Uart SPI. why we don't write simple program to send data serially? why do we use these protocols for serial communication ?

Comment: because the device on the other ends speaks some specific bus and protocol.

Comment: unclear what you’re asking — Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if we interface LCD (16*2) to 8051. simple we write c program to send data from 8051 to LCD and if we interface RTC to 8051 we use I2C Protocols to send or receive data from 8051 to RTC. why Don't we write simple program for RTC. why we use I2C protocols ?